# How can I implement routing for an extended routes in the RouteConfig file without creating a route error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I implemented a logout link in an ASP.NET MVC 5 application (C#), and it works perfectly with the current routing of my application:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

When I log in, I see the logout button and it works seamlessly.

However, I have other areas of the app that are designated for registered users (for which I have not considered the routing), and after going to an area designed for authorized users and I attempt to log out, I get the following path returned when the browser displays an error:

```
/Managers/Home/LogOff
```

I have a home controller with an action link of Logoff, but I'm uncertain how to represent my Managers folder (along with others on that level). And I could not find (and really, I have not searched exhaustively) readily available documentation of routing beyond what I implement in my routes.MapRoute file (seen above). I would appreciate it if someone can steer me in the right direction or tell me the correct pattern to use. I can't imagine the issue being anything other than routing. Thanks!

RouteConfig.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace HRCoreUS
{
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated my verbiage. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: How do you register the Managers area?

Comment: I added the web.config

Comment: ...and I have yet to implement attribute routes in any of my controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options for you to define a route that suits you.

Fist one, if you want to log off all users from a specific folder, you can use a route like the following one. The keyword 'allusers' prevents you to have a conflict with your Default route. This also make your route more 'readable'.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "LogOffAllUserFromFolder",
    "{controller}/{action}/allusers/{folder}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Logoff", folder = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

This endpoint would then looks like :

```
/home/logoff/allusers/Managers
```

Second one, if you want to log off a specific user (for example user with id 124) from a 'Managers' folder, you can try the following route that won't conflict with Default since there are 4 arguments

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "LogOffSpecificUserFromFolder",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{folder}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Logoff", id = RouteParameter.Optional, folder = RouteParameter.Optional },
    new { id = @"\d+" });
```

The endpoint would then looks like

```
/home/logoff/124/Managers
```

As you're id is an int I suppose, you can tell it by adding that to your route definition

```
new { id = @"\d+" }
```

And as {folder} is a string you don't need any other definition as it is the default type.

If I missunderstand your point, I hope this will gives you tips on how to declare MVC routes.

Take care.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Attribute routing inside your Controllers folder Simply create a ManagersController

```
[RoutePrefix("managers")]
public class ManagerController
```

Then simply add a `[Route("")]` attribute on every function inside the controller.
Depending on any URL parameters you need define them in the Route attribute.

```
[HttpGet, Route("logoff}")]
public HttpResponseMessage LogOff() //route would be Managers/logoff
[HttpGet, Route("{id:int/view-profile}")]
public HttpResponseMessage ViewProfile(int id) //route would be Managers/4/view-profile
[HttpPost, Route("{id:guid/save-profile}")]
public HttpResponseMessage ViewProfile(Guid id) //route would be Managers/405750C8-0B3F-4EF2-A2A2-17A1EFBCDA39/save-profile
```

More info on attributes - 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

or for general catchall maproute in Routeconfig you would want something like this:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Make sure this is the last route defined in your RouteConfig.

Then inside a ManagersController.cs create a

```
public HttpResponseMessage LogOff()
```

This Route would be `localhost.com/managers/logoff`

But from how I interpreted your question it seems as if your Authentication logic is tied to a specific controller (Home)? You should have all that logic encapsulated in something like a AuthenticationController which could handle your login / logoff logic. This way its not dependent on anything else and you could have a route like this:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Authentication",
        url: "authentication/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Authentication", action = "Index"}
    );
```

with a Login / LogOff Function. These would route to `/authentication/login` and `/authentication/logoff`

Comment: I attempted the general catchall maproute example from your response, and the browser returned the following: "A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server."

Comment: Add `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` to the web.config

Also make sure that that Route is after your original route